# setPasswordPath doesn't seem to be working

Tags: admin, password

This looks like a bug to me:
If I set the `setPasswordPath` in the general config file, then the template that I've set up is not showing up, it loads the default one when I try to load:

`http://site.local/admin/actions/users/setpassword?code=`

Comment: Bugs should be reported directly to support@craftcms.com

Comment: `setPasswordPath` only applies to front end requests – as per [the official docs](https://craftcms.com/docs/config-settings#setPasswordPath) on the subject – maybe that's the issue here (the OP's description is a bit unclear)?

Comment: I've read that, but I don't understand what "only applies to front end requests" means.